# NHibernate 4 only supports generic collections. Any solution for upgrading?

Tags: nhibernate, generic-list

I have many NH entities that use non generic list. (using `generic="false"` and `IList`)
I have downloaded NH4 and noticed that NH4 does not support persisting non generic list. While saving I got this exception :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.

Is there any simple solution to upgrade my NH entities?

```
public virtual IList TemplateProperties
{
    get
    {
        return this._TemplateProperties;
    }
    set
    {
        this._TemplateProperties = value;
    }
}

<bag name="TemplateProperties" generic="false">
  <key>
    <column name="PRPT_ID" not-null="true" precision="10" scale="0" sql-type="int" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="TemplateProperty" />
</bag>
```

Comment: Why can't you replace `IList` with `IList<object>` and `ArrayList` with `List<object>`? `List<object>` does implement IList if an API might need it.

Comment: My framework works with IList for composited entities. IList<object> is not IList.

Answer (score 1):

change the implementation of the models to use generic lists. They are still handed out as IList

```
private readonly List<object>_TemplateProperties = new List<object>();
public virtual IList TemplateProperties
{
    get { return this._TemplateProperties; }
}
```

Then specify in the mapping to use the field instead of the property access the value

```
<bag name="TemplateProperties" access="field.pascalcase-underscore">
```

Comment: set { this._TemplateProperties = value; }



Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.IList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) .

Comment: Hm the setter shouldn't be there, forgot to delete it. Do you really need to set the property from outside? It would be a source of bugs anyway (disconnects NHibernates change tracking collections).

Comment: I think I have to switch to generic list. There's no a straightforward solution.
Thanks a lot Firo.